# Return class variable of a Laravel Model in JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following model class

```
class MyModel extends Model {
    public $some_variable; // I don't want to store this in the database
    protected $fillable = ['column1', 'column2'];
```

In the controller:

```
$model = MyModel::find(2);
$model->some_variable = "some value"; // Dynamically calculated each time
return response()->json($model);
```

The response contains all the columns from `MyModel` but does not contain `$some_variable`. Why could this be happening? Are class variables transient by default?

Answer (score 0):

Model's data is internally kept in `$attributes` array, so you may want to put it there prior converting your data to JSON:

```
...
$model->some_variable = ...;
return response()->json($model);
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try adding it to the `$attributes` array.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have defined `$some_variable` on the Model, it will not show up in the array/json output. The array/json output only includes the table data (stored in the `$attributes` property) and the loaded relationship data.

If you want this field to show up, you can override the `toArray()` method on the model, or you could create an accessor method and add that to the `$appends` property.

Override `toArray()`:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public $some_variable;

    public function toArray()
    {
        $data = parent::toArray();
        $data['some_variable'] = $this->some_variable;

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Use an accessor and `$appends`:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    public $some_variable;

    protected $appends = ['some_variable'];

    public function getSomeVariableAttribute()
    {
        return $this->some_variable;
    }

}
```

You can read about [accessors here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). You can read about [appending data to json here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json).

Comment: I'll try this and get back to you! Thanks!